# How to make smooth change of css property while scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I have a task - my navigation block has background property `background: rgba(0,0,0, 0);`
I need to smooth change its opacity from 0 to 1 while scrolling, its no problem, but the end of animation (i mean the moment when opacity of background will reach 1) is bottom border of some block

so this is my `HTML` code

```
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</header>
```

`header` has a flexible height. `nav` has a height of 100px. So i need my nav`s background opacity to reach 1 when scrollTop value will be:

```
$('header').height() - $(nav).height();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zzvns9hy/7/

Comment: Could you create an example in jsfiddle please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zzvns9hy/7/

Comment: I thought your question was regarding JQuery, which is not included into the jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zzvns9hy/8/

Comment: Check this out please: http://jsfiddle.net/dbdstefan/bs7jbdxh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // what is the position of nav from the top of the document
    var NavTop = Math.floor( $(document).scrollTop() - $('nav').offset().top );
    // From 0 to 1, how much is nav scrolled
    var NavScroll = NavTop / $('nav').height(); 

    $('nav').css('background-color','rgba(255,0,0,'+NavScroll+')');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/an50e93p/